# Change url in codeigniter with searches term

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing, codeigniter-3

I have links like this

```
http://example.com/search/texas
```

I want it to route to a controller `search` and the URL should be

`http://example.com/schools-in-texas`

**What I have done so far**

On route

```
$route['search/(:any)'] = "search"; //search is a controller
```

On search controller I get the town name `texas` using

```
$x = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

I want to query the database and use the result to open a search template with the url being `http://example.com/schools-in-texas` where `texas` is the search term.

I redirect to the url but doesn't load the data from database so it's not working as expected.

```
$url = $this->uri->segment(2);
redirect('schools-in-'.$url, 'refresh');
```

Can someone provide any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a controller called schools-in-texas?

Comment: @Fil I dont have a controller called schools-in-texas because there are several links, i want it to be dynamic else i will have to create all controllers for all the states and towns like "schools-in-alabama" etc 

I want when you click a link of alabama its queries the database on the search controller and loads view with the data from database and view will have url of www.example.com/schools-in-alabama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this for routing

```
$route['schools-in-(:any)'] = 'search';
```

This will take into `Search` controller when your URL will be like `http://example.com/schools-in-texas`

And to get the word `texas` from URL (for search term) now you may use

```
$state_name = substr($this->uri->segment(1), strrpos($this->uri->segment(1), '-') + 1);
```

now `$state_name` will output as `texas` if you URL http://example.com/schools-in-texas

Comment: interesting, didnt know i can do this $route['schools-in-(:any)'] = 'search';